# How to calculate the number of ways to climb a building if only $1$ or $2$ floors can be climbed each time with elevator possibility at some floor?

Tags: proof-verification, algorithms, recurrence-relations, proof-explanation, recursion

> Let there be $n$ floors ($n<30$) in some building. In order to arrive to the $n$-th floor we can climb one or two floors each time. On floor $20$ there's an elevator. If we arrive to the $20$-th floor we must take the elevator to the $n$-th floor. Design recursive algorithm to determine in  how many ways it is possible to climb to the $n$-th floor? (if $29<n$ or $n<20$ then there're $0$ ways).

For example:

1. the person can climb to the $19$-th floor, climbing one or two floors at a time, then climb two floors to floor $21$ and then continue climbing one or two floors at a time until reaching $n$-th floor.
2. the person can climb $20$ floors than the person must take the elevator to the $n$-th floor

---

Without the elevator constraint the problem may be solved using the following recurrence:
$$
f(0) = 1\\f(-1)=0\\
f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)
$$
Through trial and error process I think to solve the problem with elevator constraint we can design formula $f'(n)$:
$$
f'(n)=f(n)-f(20)-f(19)-f(18)
$$
Intuitively this makes sense: we subtract $f(20)$ from $f'(n)$ because all climb paths after arriving to floor $20$ are illegal as we must take the elevator. But why do we need to subtract $f(19)$ and $f(18)$? Because they can lead to floor $20$?

I'm not sure if $f'(n)$ is correct and if it is why we need to subtract $f(19)$ and $f(18)$.

Comment: Are you saying that $f'(n)$ is the answer?  But...suppose $n=20$.  Then your answer is negative.  Or take $n=21$, still negative.

Comment: @lulu yes $f'(n)$ is supposed to be the answer. You brought up a good point.

Comment: I'd have said:  there are two strategies.  Get to $20$ or skip $20$.  First is easy to count.  For the second, note that the only way to skip $20$ is to get to $19$ and take a $2$, then go up the remaining $n-21$.  Also easy to count.

Comment: @lulu I'd think first we calculate $f(19)$ then add $f(n)-f(21)$ but this doesn't work

Comment: $f(a-b)\neq f(a)-f(b)$.  Note:  I'd work the cases of $n=21,22,23$ by hand to make sure there isn't a fencepost error.

Comment: I think I figured it out: $f(n-21)=f(n)-1-\sum_{i=0}^{21}f(i)$

Comment: Again, with $n=21$ the value on the right is clearly negative.  Don't just write down formulas without thinking!  Try some values, make sure it works for simple cases.  Anyway, why do we need anything simpler than $f(n-21)$?  certainly a formula for that that requires me to compute $f(n)$ is horribly inefficient.

Comment: @lulu if you hint at some kind of dynamic programming or saving intermediate results this is not relevant for this problem as efficiency is not important for this particular problem. Even a $O(2^n)$ complexity will be acceptable.

Comment: That's silly.  To compute the $k^{th}$ Fibonacci number there is no point computing them beyond $k$.  But, really, check your formulas.  Test them for small cases.  Don't just rely on formal manipulations.

Comment: Maybe you are missing the point.  Ignore the fact that your formula gives negative values.  Say $n=23$.  Then all you want to compute is $f(2)$.  Trivial!  But your formula would require me to compute $f(0),f(1),\cdots, f(23)$.  Why?  If nothing else, note that $f(2)$ already appears on the right.  If I know that value...why am I bothering with all the others?

Comment: @lulu true, $f(n-21)$ doesn't give the required answer either. For example  $f(23)\neq f(19)+f(2)$. I realize that to calculate $f(23)$ it's not enough to just calculate $ f(19)+f(2)$ because this will not represent the true recursion tree. That's why I wanted to calculate the complement of $f(n-21)$

Comment: No idea what you are saying.  I've given you enough hints to solve the problem (just shy of a full solution, really, though, seriously, check for fencepost errors).  Good luck!

Comment: @lulu I wasn't able to solve the problem by reusing $f(n)$ but I do get a correct result if I adjust the original recurrence to the following: $$f(0)=1\\f(-1)=0\\f(21)=f(19)\\f(n) = f(n-1)+f(n-2)$$

Comment: That doesn't look right.  There is only one way to get to $22$ from $21$, for instance, but according to you $f(22)=f(21)+f(20)$.

Comment: Indeed, to get to $22$ you need to get to $19$ ($f(19)$ ways), then go up two (one way), then go up one (one way).  So $f(22)=f(19)$, in your notation.